# Trying to access data from inside array php

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#392 (12) {
    ["answer_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_question"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_user"]=>
    int(132)
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(10) "2020-05-13"
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Se la respuesta"
    ["description"]=>
    string(6) "Patata"
    ["likes"]=>
    int(17)
    ["views"]=>
    int(0)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2020-05-09 13:58:19"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "usuario"
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(132)
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(7) "usuario"
  }

}
```

I am trying to access  "answer_id" but I've tried and nothing.

echo var_dump($threads[0]->answer_id);

I tried this and nothing.

Thanks for the help!

```
$threads = Answer::select('answers.id AS answer_id','answers.id_question', 'answers.id_user', 'answers.fecha', 'answers.title', 'answers.description', 'answers.likes' , 'answers.views','users.created_at', 'users.first_name',  'users.id AS user_id','users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'answers.id_user')
->where('answers.id_question', '=', $id)
->get()
->toJson();
```

Comment: Is "answer_id" a private member? If so you will have to either make it public or write an accessor.

Comment: I presume in `stdClass` there're no private properties.

Comment: No, I've tried to get the first name or another field and it return:     Trying to get property 'fecha' of non-object

Comment: What __exactly__ `var_dump($threads[0])` shows?

Comment: string(1) "["  It only returns this character

Comment: Hm, and `var_dump($threads)` then?

Comment: The entire array

Comment: No, this can't happen. Maybe `$threads` is a __string__, a json?

Comment: It's a json because I am getting this array of select in laravel

Comment: Then decode this string and ony after decoding use `->` notation.

Comment: Also - __why__ do you use `toJson()` if you don't need json?

Comment: The decode works! I used toJson() because I didn't know if there was another way. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Remove `toJson()`, you will get a plain array of objects or array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode it first and then after that you can access the information with ->

$array= json_decode($threads);
$array[0]->answer_id);

Comment: As noted in comments, it makes more sense to not use `toJson()` in the first place...